# Contribution Amount via Webform Conditionals (Error)

Tags: webform-civicrm

I use CiviCRM Webform Integration for Event Registration and Payment ; and I use Conditionals to calculate the Contribution Amount :

If ... Then Conditional Amount is set to 45,00  (french format)

When I submit the registration, I get the following error :

Warning : preg_match(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 464 dans webform_number_format_match() (ligne 831 dans /home/paroisse/public_html/test/drupal/sites/all/modules/webform/components/number.inc).
Contribution Amount field value must format numbers as "12 345,68".

(But, if I set this Conditional Amount = 45,00 manually, the submission is OK.)

Is there any explanation for this error ?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a Drupal problem :

Even if you work in french, you must define every numeric Webform fields in english format (coma thousand separator, period decimal separator).

Contribution amount is an example, but the same problem exists also for any numeric Webform "new component".